# DisplayName of a serialized property does not change (Scriptable Object - Editor Script)

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity-editor, scriptable-object

I am writing an Editor Script for a scriptable object. This is my requirement.

1. I have a few options defined by an Enum. (E_Joint -> HIP, KNEE, SHOULDER)
2. In the scriptable object, I change the enum to Knee.
3. There is a string variable "panelName". The string value needs to change (which works) and the display name needs to change as well (Which does not seem to work).

Here is the code.

```
public class ApplicationSetup : ScriptableObject
{
    public E_BuildOption ebuildOption;
    public E_Joint eJoint;

    [SerializeReference]
    public string panelName;
}
```

Here is the Editor Script:

```
[CustomEditor(typeof(ApplicationSetup))]
    public class ApplicationSetupEditor : Editor
    {
        SerializedProperty mJoint;
        SerializedProperty mPanel;

        ApplicationSetup appSetup;
        private void OnEnable()
        {
            mJoint = serializedObject.FindProperty("eJoint");
            mPanel = serializedObject.FindProperty("panelName");
            appSetup = (ApplicationSetup)target;
        }
        public override void OnInspectorGUI()
        {
            //DrawDefaultInspector()
            serializedObject.Update();

            DrawPropertiesExcluding(serializedObject,
            new string[] {"m_Script", "eJoint", "panelName"});

            GUIContent content = new GUIContent("Panel Name");

            EditorGUI.BeginChangeCheck();
            EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(mJoint);
            if(EditorGUI.EndChangeCheck())
            {
                E_Joint joint = (E_Joint)mJoint.enumValueIndex;
                
                // Check joint type
                switch(joint)
                {
                    // If knee joint
                    case E_Joint.KNEE:
                        // Set panel name to KneeOption
                        mPanel.stringValue = "KneeOption";
                        // Set content text to Knee Option
                        content.text = "Knee Option";
                        break;

                    // If hip joint  
                    case E_Joint.HIP:
                        // Set panel name to HipOption
                        mPanel.stringValue = "HipOption";
                        // Set content text to Hip Option
                        content.text = "Hip Option";
                        break;

                    // If shoulder joint
                    case E_Joint.SHOULDER:
                        // Set panel name to ShoulderOption
                        mPanel.stringValue = "ShoulderOption";
                        // Set content text to Shoulder Option
                        content.text = "Shoulder Option";
                        break;

                    // Default case
                    default:
                        // Set panel name to DefaultOption
                        mPanel.stringValue = "DefaultOption";
                        // Set content text to Default Option
                        content.text = "Default Option";
                        break;
                }
            }
            EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(mPanel, content);
            
            serializedObject.ApplyModifiedProperties();
        }
    }
```

Attaching a screenshot of what is happening

[image]

Am I missing something here?
Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks!

---

**Update**

Found the fix.
It was silly.

Since this is running every frame, it was setting the name to PanelName.
I just saved the GUIContent onEnable.

Updated Editor script.

```
public class ApplicationSetupEditor : Editor
    {
        SerializedProperty mJoint;
        SerializedProperty mPanel;

        ApplicationSetup appSetup;
        
        GUIContent panelContent;
        
        private void OnEnable()
        {
            mJoint = serializedObject.FindProperty("eJoint");
            mPanel = serializedObject.FindProperty("panelName");
            appSetup = (ApplicationSetup)target;
            panelContent = new GUIContent(appSetup.panelName);
        }
        public override void OnInspectorGUI()
        {
            //DrawDefaultInspector()
            serializedObject.Update();

            DrawPropertiesExcluding(serializedObject,
            new string[] {"m_Script", "eJoint", "panelName"});

            EditorGUI.BeginChangeCheck();
            EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(mJoint);
            if(EditorGUI.EndChangeCheck())
            {
                E_Joint joint = (E_Joint)mJoint.enumValueIndex;
                // Check joint type
                switch(joint)
                {
                    // If knee joint
                    case E_Joint.KNEE:
                        // Set panel name to KneeOption
                        mPanel.stringValue = "KneeOption";
                        // Set content text to Knee Option
                        panelContent.text = "Knee Option";
                        break;

                    // If hip joint  
                    case E_Joint.HIP:
                        // Set panel name to HipOption
                        mPanel.stringValue = "HipOption";
                        // Set content text to Hip Option
                        panelContent.text = "Hip Option";
                        break;

                    // If shoulder joint
                    case E_Joint.SHOULDER:
                        // Set panel name to ShoulderOption
                        mPanel.stringValue = "ShoulderOption";
                        // Set content text to Shoulder Option
                        panelContent.text = "Shoulder Option";
                        break;

                    // Default case
                    default:
                        // Set panel name to DefaultOption
                        mPanel.stringValue = "DefaultOption";
                        // Set content text to Default Option
                        panelContent.text = "Default Option";
                        break;
                }
                
            }
            
            EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(mPanel, panelContent);
            serializedObject.ApplyModifiedProperties();
        }
    }
```

This worked.